# Bootstrap select plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use [this Bootstrap-Select Plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.com/bootstrap-select/). I have created a fiddle also according to the demo,

http://jsbin.com/anepet/1/edit

But i am totally blank and not understand why this is not working, the appearance of select list is not changing, can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Thanks for showing me a plugin I haven't seen before too. Select looks really good. I current use Select2 http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps add the invocation to make all `.selectpicker` elements a selectpicker? You will pretty much hit your head after seeing this. In the source of the Select plugin page you will see countless times where the demo uses a css selector to invoke `.selectpicker()` on the elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
```

Please see. http://jsbin.com/anepet/3/edit

Answer (score 2):

You are including the js twice and not invoking the `selectpicker()`..

remove this line:
    `<script src="http://silviomoreto.github.com/bootstrap-select/javascripts/bootstrap-select.js"></script>`

and add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

in the `<header>` and it will work